# New Column to populate with If/Or statement

Tags: function, if-statement

newbie trying to add a new column containing the result of an if or statement.

the if statement is below, trying to include it in a function - not sure if this is necessary?

Currently the below just returns 'None'

```
    T30_IRE['Aff Mod']=affmod()
    def affmod():
        if ['AccountLevel3']=='Derivatives (L1)':
            'Third Party'
        elif ['AccountLevel5']=='Economic Hedges (Reversal) - Ruby Forecast Only (L3)': 
            'Third Party'
        else : 
            ['AffiliateLevel3']
              
    T30_IRE['Aff Mod']=affmod()'`
```